# Spring Data JPA IN clause returning more than expected values, when any element of list, to be passed is having hyphen in it

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

While fetching records using IN clause, the below query is returning more than expected values.

```
List`<Object>` findAllByCameraIdIn(List`<String>` cameraIds);
```

I have records associated with two cameras in elastic db - [uk05-smoking-shelter-carpark, uk05-stairway-in]

**If List cameraIds = ["uk05-smoking-shelter-carpark"], it's giving values associated with camera -> uk05-stairway-in also (both cameras), Any idea/suggestion why this is happing ?**

Even if I'm making db call to filter the records, expected result should have been only 7, corresponding to `uk05-smoking-shelter-carpark` but it is giving me results for `uk05-stairway-in` also.

[image]

---

**My Findings**

When I replaced the - with _ for few records i.e., `(uk05-smoking-shelter-carpark with uk05_smoking_shelter_carpark)` in the cameraId, the query is working fine.

[image]

I believe the query starts searching for all the records with the given value but once it enconters `-` , it's ignoring all the letters after the `-` . Any suggestion or insights why it is like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) if no analyzer is specified. Assuming `cameraId` field is of `text` type, so `uk05-smoking-shelter-carpark` will get tokenized into

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "uk05",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "smoking",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "shelter",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "carpark",
      "start_offset": 21,
      "end_offset": 28,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

So when searching for `"uk05-smoking-shelter-carpark"` will match all the documents that have any of the tokens shown above.

---

1. If you want to return the documents that match exactly with the search query then you need to change the data type of `cameraId` to `keyword` type
2. OR if you have not explicitly defined any mapping then you need to add .keyword to the `cameraId` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after `cameraId` field).
3. It is better to use a [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) if you are searching for an exact term match.

**Search Query using match query**

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "cameraId.keyword":"uk05_smoking_shelter_carpark"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query using term query**

```
{
  "query":{
    "term":{
      "cameraId.keyword":"uk05_smoking_shelter_carpark"
    }
  }
}
```

---

When you replace `-` with `_`, i.e `"uk05_smoking_shelter_carpark"`, this will get tokenized into

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "uk05_smoking_shelter_carpark"
}
```

Token generated will be

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "uk05_smoking_shelter_carpark",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 28,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case, the search query will only return the documents that match `uk05_smoking_shelter_carpark`

Comment: yes, with `.keyword` it's working fine. Thanks for the explanation, it was very insight full.
In terms of spring data jpa query perspective, any suggestion on how to handle this situation other than the term query

Comment: @RahulKumar I am not quite familiar with spring data jpa query, but I believe you can use `term` query or`match_phrase` query also to achieve your requirement. Even you can get your result with `match` query using the `.keyword` field.